# Failed to load video on android tv using google cast

Tags: android

I am trying to cast a video on android tv using google cast. On Media route button click cast is connected to tv but when I send a video uri video is not loaded on tv

```
private fun castVideo(uri: Uri) {
        if (mCastSession == null)
            mCastSession = CastContext.getSharedInstance(
                requireContext(),
                localExecutor
            ).result.sessionManager.currentCastSession

        if (mCastSession != null) {
            val metadata = MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE)
            metadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Video Title")
            metadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "Video Subtitle")

            val mediaInfo = MediaInfo.Builder(uri.toString())
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("video/mp4")
                .setMetadata(metadata)
                .build()

            val mediaRequest = MediaLoadRequestData.Builder()
                .setMediaInfo(mediaInfo)
                .setAutoplay(true)
                .setCurrentTime(0)
                .build()

            val remoteMediaClient = mCastSession?.remoteMediaClient

            remoteMediaClient?.load(mediaRequest)
                ?.setResultCallback {
                    if (it.status.isSuccess) {
                        errorLog("successfully launched video")
                    } else {
                        errorLog("error code:${it.status.statusCode}")
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

on click of a video video title and subtitle are sent and displayed on android tv loading seekbar is also displayed but it's failed to load

Comment: Are there any error codes or exceptions?

Comment: @MESP I tried mediaLoadResult.status.statusMessage but it was null it's only showing statusCode